# Construct a Hash collection that can be sorted by time of insertion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting, ruby-on-rails-4, hashmap

From time to time I'm inserting key-value pairs to a `Hash`.

How can I construct this Hash such that I can sort the pairs by the `Time` they were created?

If I create a nested `Hash` where the key would be a timestamp (in `String` format I suppose) and the value the value-key pair - would that be "easy" to sort chronologically then or is there any better way?

Comment: You need to code for that... By adding a time value with each key...

Comment: So I would construct the Hash like this `{"06 Jan 2014 11:04:05" => {"k1" => "v33"}}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Hash](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html%20%22) already behaves like that. Basically, the elements are ordered based on the time you inserted the element.

> Hashes enumerate their values in the order that the corresponding keys were inserted.

[Source](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html%20%22)

Comment: Ah great, i thought they weren't! But as long as I'm on Ruby `> 1.9` I should be good I assume.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply set your keys as a timestamps each time you insert a value to your hash.

For ex:

```
your_hash = {}
unique_timestamp = Time.now.to_s #time key as a string (you can create it each time 
                                 #you want to insert a value)
your_hash[unique_timestamp] = "new_value"
```

So, you can inspect your hash like "your_hash.inspect" and you will see your key as a string timestamp format and then your value.